# SQL database export-import

Tags: mysql

I develop websites containing WordPress blogs as well as other PHP pages I design. When I make changes to sites locally on my test server I do a SQL database dump using myPHPAdmin. How can I avoid overwriting the content of the client's WordPress Calendar entrys and other Calendar settings? If I simply deselect the calendar tables on my localhost db dump will the client's db maintain those client entry to the tables on the remote server after the import?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe.  What calendar plugin are they using?  In the future, why not pull their site down, make changes to that, and then push back to production?  You shouldn't need to do much to the live database that can't be accomplished with a few minutes of downtime while you assign pages to templates and what not.

Answer (score 2):

backup only all tables you need from localhost so your .sql file contain only the tables you need & after this go to your live server keep your databse as it 
the use the following cmd from unix/linux SSH to keep the old tables & only restore the new tables

```
mysql -u username -ppassword databasename -D < /pathto/datbase.sql
```

this cmd is used for restoring only some tables & let other tables as it

don't forget please backup every thing before trying this to avoid any problems

Comment: Pretty clever. Would this be typically doable by pure php? I don't know the PHP db drivers very well, can they do a dump restore like this in a simple way?

Comment: Glad this help, this is command not you can use it from mysql console or from SSH, i think there is alot of alternative ways with PHP, but this is for the big 7 huge sizes is better